# How to use printer without permision from admin?

Tags: windows-server-2008, printing

My scenario is: I'm an admin of a window server 2012 R2. I create 2 group: "student" and "teacher", "student" can access to "studen" folder only and teacher access to "teacher" folder only.

Also there are 2 printer 1 for each group. They are only able to use their printer, the others can't.

So is there anyway for a student in "student" group able to print from "teacher" printer (Student don't have permision to access to admin role) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with network attached printers, in case the "students" have admin access on clients (laptops/desktops) or are able to change/add print queues. A "Student" simple install local queue with printer IP as a port. Domain permissions are not applied in such scenario.